# How To handle Large Tasks in flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, task, web-worker

I'm using flask framework for
e-commerce website which add a watermark to every product image
and I want to add command in flask cli which regenerate all images
but there is a lot of images about 80,000 image
how can I manage to this task

Comment: Your question is quite broad, can you give more details to what exactly you want to achieve, first question I'd ask is: do you care about real-time processing,  or do you want to pre-process those image files?, second how much resources can you use in terms of memory and processing power?, what's the nature of the deployment?

Comment: Thank your for replying
It would take more than 3 hours
So i want to make this process in background
I don't have much resources and i don't care about real time-time

Comment: well You could check out the [`Pillow`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library that allows to easily work with images.

Comment: i'm already using pillow the problem is this task takes alot of time and i want to make this task run in background

Comment: K, based on what I understood, I'd use a multi-process solution instead of processing the images on the same thread or process, what you want is seperate the image files into batches, and then either use threads or processes to do the work in parallel, that would significantly reduce time taken. See what suites your need - usually when you say background it's either a process or a thread - after that the question is if you want them to share memory or no, thats the difference between a process and a thread, I encourage you to read about that.

Answer (score 0):

What I will suggest to use below approach (I am doing for fetching large amount of Data):

Write a script in Python which takes image name / path as parameter and keeps running in background or may be a cron. It will keep on checking your DB or Kafka where when image is uploaded events will be published.

From flask you just need to keep on reading the status of task or do some async call using ajax to keep on publishing the status

or you can just send a CLI command as below:

```
import os
os.system('Your command with parameter(s)')
```

Overall I can see you will have to use combination of some background job along with Ajax or Async calls

For Making the processing faster, you can use threading. But make sure that your system memory is sufficient and open file limits are good enough. In case there is crunch or you want to make it optimized. Put a sleep in your image processing funtion for some time. Pseudo code as below:

```
'''python
import threading
import time
import os

def funImageProcessor(self, argImagePath,Arg2):
    #do your Stuffs here
    time.sleep(3) #use this to run your threads in optimal way 

for image in Images:
    threadImg = threading.Thread(target=funImageProcessor, args=(
            self, argImagePath,Arg2))                
            self.threadsImg.append(threadImg)
            threadImg.start()
for tpo in self.threadsImg:
    tpo.join()
'''
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer
But my problem is not how to implement the command my problem is this command would take more than 3 hours how to make this command after calling work in background

Comment: I have added pseudo code as per requirement. Please do upvote if this helps

Comment: Images will be a batch or list as per your defined criteria. May be you are filling this list on the base of timestamp or id